# Wix Force Overwrite of files for One Folder

Tags: wix

I have several directories and files as part of my installation. One of the folders I want to replace the contents always and the remaining follow the default Wix behavior. I noticed I can setup REINSTALLMODE to "amus", but does this apply to the entire package?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182(v=VS.85).aspx

http://wix.mindcapers.com/wiki/MSIExec

How do I use

```
<Property Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="amus" />
```

on a single directory or component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't support doing that.

Comment: Is there something I can do with removefolder on both? The folder may have been created by the user manually prior to having an installer and I want to replace the folder contents. The default file replacement rules don't seem to do that.

Comment: Yes, you could use RemoveFile element to delete things from the folder. The RemoveFiles action comes before the InstallFiles action so the timing will work out. Note: this behavior would happen during repair, upgrade, and patching as well so be sure to test that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer might not "support" that, but it certainly can be done with version lying.